# Getting User ID From a Command

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there any way to get the user ID of the person who uses a particular command?

I tried to make a test command to see how I could do it, but I can't seem to make it work

```
@client.command()
async def icri(ctx, message):
    await ctx.send(message.author.user_id)
```

I tried making this work but when I ran the command as `!icri xyz` with the thought that if xyz is taken as the message, it would return the user id. But when I ran it, I got an error message saying that the function is missing the argument 'message'.

My final aim is to create a command that would find the user id of the member who uses the command and access a dictionary item associated with it.
I could do that if I do something like this

```
@client.command()
async def icri(ctx, member):
    await ctx.send(member.user_id)
```

but that's impractical and I want it to be a covert thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `message` is just a parameter you passed. So it's not the `message` object. If you get the message tou can get it with `ctx.message`. Also look these:

```
ctx.guild => Server
ctx.channel => The text channel
ctx.message => The message
ctx.author => Who sent the message
ctx.author.id => User's id
```

You can get more information in https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bots

Comment: So, in my await ctx.send, I do await ctx.message.send?

I'm relatively new at this, so idk much, sorry

Comment: You told, you want to get user's id. So type `await ctx.send(ctx.author.id)`